# RoR routes explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Can you explain me what these lines of code do ?

```
resources :posts, :pages do
      post 'preview', :on => :collection
    end

resources :undo_items do
      post 'undo', :on => :member
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :posts, :pages do
```

will create standard/default RESTful routes for posts and pages (`GET` `POST` /posts, `GET` `PUT` `DESTROY` /posts/1, `GET` /pages/1/edit and etc).

```
 post 'preview', :on => :collection
```

will add additional route for collection. `POST` /posts/preview. if it said `:on => :member` than route would be for a member and would look like this `POST` /posts/1/preview.

That's a quick guide so you can get your head around. But as Robert K suggested, I also highly recommend going over rails guides. They are very well written and easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

The guides for Ruby on Rails are rather complete. I suggest you read about [Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web).